# Overlay positioning over specific widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, overlay

I am new to Flutter and have been trying to find the answer to this question for weeks.

I am writing a simple game and want to display some feedback in an overlay widget. What I am having trouble with is understanding how to

1. make the overlay appear over any specific widget (without resorting to absolute coordinates) and
2. make its size the same as the widget below. (I'm not sure what widget can be used for displaying text in a box with given dimensions.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is one version of what I have tried:

```
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      // Multiplication Table widget
      CompositedTransformTarget(
        link: resultDisplayLink,
        child: Table(
          children: populateMultiplicationTable(),
        ),
      ),
// .... some code here that is not relevant to the question ... 

// The code to show the container over the Table widget
  void showResult(BuildContext context, bool correct) async {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry resultDisplay = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              child: CompositedTransformFollower(
                offset: Offset(
                  offset.dx,
                  offset.dy,
                ),
                link: resultDisplayLink,
                child: Text((correct) ? 'Yes!' : 'No...'),
              ),
            ));
    overlayState.insert(resultDisplay);

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    resultDisplay.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Please share your codes on what you have tried

Comment: Hi @Reign, I have just added the code that I have tried to the question.

Comment: did you see this library (The Easiest way for overlay ) .. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal

Comment: I haven't, but I will check it out, thank you.